# how to add last three lines of textarea to three different variables?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have a html file with textarea tag in which i will copy and paste some text with multiple lines and i want to get the last three lines each separately in three different variables using javascript.
***textarea is assigned an id="txt".***
**Function clicked is assigned to a button in html file.**

```
function clicked(){
var txt = document.getElementById("txt");
var original = txt.value; //original text transfered to original variable

var lastline =  //add last line in this variable

var secondlast = //add second last line in this variable

var thirdlast = //add third last line in this variable

var modified = //add text without these three lines in this variable


console.log(lastline); //how are you
console.log(secondlast); //now is the time
console.log(thirdlast); //helloo  there
console.log(modified); //school data is the important
//checking home
//not there
}
```

text inputed in textarea:

```
school data is the important
checking home
not there
helloo  there
now is the time
how are you
```

output:

```
how are you

now is the time

helloo  there

school data is the important
checking home
not there
```

Comment: Use `split` on `original` and work your way back from the end of the resulting array.

Comment: can you please explain how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple function:

```
function letsgo() {
  var area= document.getElementById("mytext"),
  //get all the lines in the textarea, seperated by \n or \r\n
      lines = area.value.match(/[^\r\n]+/g),
  //get bottom 3 lines, reverse them
      bottom3 = lines.slice(-3).reverse();

  var lastline=bottom3[0];
  var secondlast=bottom3[1];
  var thirdlast=bottom3[2];

  //get all text except bottom 3 lines, joining them together with linefeed again
  var rest = lines.slice(0, -3).join("\n");

  //glue bottom3 and rest together
  var result=bottom3.join("\n")+"\n"+rest;

  //put in the textarea again
  area.value=result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Line breaks within the `value` of a textarea are represented by line break characters rather than an HTML `<br>` element,].

You can get the individual lines by normalizing the line  breaks to `\n` and then calling the `split()` method on the textarea's value.

Here is a utility function that calls a function for every line of a textarea value:

```
function actOnEachLine(textarea, func) {
    var lines = textarea.value.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n").split("\n");
    var newLines, i;

    // Use the map() method of Array where available 
    if (typeof lines.map != "undefined") {
        newLines = lines.map(func);
    } else {
        newLines = [];
        i = lines.length;
        while (i--) {
            newLines[i] = func(lines[i]);
        }
    }
    textarea.value = newLines.join("\r\n");
}

var textarea = document.getElementById("txt");
var lines;  // Store your lines in an array
actOnEachLine(textarea, function(line) {
    lines.push(line) //
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works simply.

```js
var lastline,secondlast,thirdlast,modified;
function parse()
{
    var elem = document.getElementById("txt");
    var text = elem.value;
    var arr = text.replace(/\n/g,"$").split("$");
    if(arr.length) lastline = arr.pop();
    if(arr.length) secondlast = arr.pop();
    if(arr.length) thirdlast = arr.pop();
    modified = arr.join("\n");
    console.log(lastline,secondlast,thirdlast);
    console.log(modified);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txt"></textarea>
<button onclick="parse()">Parse</button>
```